# Inserting view to another view OnClick in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a main screen with a bunch of tiles (think Windows 8), and when clicked, a sub-menu will slide out underneath the clicked tile (Think iOS folders).

I know there's property animation that I can use for the slide-out effect, but I'm not sure how to actually insert the new view. It'll be an XML-based LinearLayout (probably).

This function is being called onPress from XML:

```
    public void mainButtonPress(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn1:
            Log.d("info","Button ONE");
            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            Log.d("info","Button TWO");
            break;
        case R.id.btn3:
            Log.d("info","Button THREE");
            break;
        case R.id.btn4:
            Log.d("info","Button FOUR");
            break;
        case R.id.btn5:
            Log.d("info","Button FIVE");
            break;
        case R.id.btn6:
            Log.d("info","Button SIX");
            break;
    }
}
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `addView` method on the ViewGroup class (which LinearLayout and the other layouts inherit from). This will add the view you supply as a parameter to the layout.

For example, say you have a LinearLayout called myLayout which you have already got a reference to in your Activity code. When the button or whatever is pressed, either create the View you want to add to the layout in code or inflate it from XML, then call `addView` on the layout, passing the view you want to add.

```
LinearLayout myLayout = // Get the layout...

...

View viewToAdd = // Get view to add...
mylayout.addView(viewToAdd);
```

For a LinearLayout that has an orientation of vertical, this will add the new view beneath whatever is already in the layout (I'm assuming the button you click will be here initially).

It's hard to understand exactly how much you have done here, but this should be something for you to look in to anyway.

Link in Android docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View)